# rostango multiple dex files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the rostango wiki, continuing to run into problems, seems like a different error pops up with each reboot.  Right now the initial and the rostango files successfully build with catkin_make and the rostango project opens ok in android-studio 0.6.1.  However, when I try to run one of the samples, e.g. vio, I get this error:

com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;

Searching suggests that this indicates redundant jar files.  But which ones?

Here is the terminal output:

.......
:tango_vio:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:tango_vio:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:tango_vio:compileDebugJava
:tango_vio:preDexDebug
:tango_vio:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':tango_vio:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> /home/dbarry/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199443/rostango-multiple-dex-files/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2014-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I removed all my JDK versions and replaced them with a single one (Oracle JDK 7), made sure all the paths and variables (e.g., JAVA_HOME in .bashrc, javaHome in android-studio) pointed to the JDK and this went away.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22611/rudy/) on 2015-06-01**:
Can you please explain more on this solution? I try would you did but I am still having this issue. I am thinking maybe I am doing it wrong so can you go in depth what you did. Thank you.